# R: Balancing a Repeated Cross-Section Sample

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an unbalanced panel of repeated cross sectional data with different number of observations with different number of ages of individuals by sampling year something like the following:

```
mydata <- data.frame(age = sample(60, 1000, replace=TRUE), 
                 year=sample(3,1000, replace=TRUE), 
                 x=rnorm(1000))
```

I would like to balance my cross sections panels so that there is an equal number of ages for each cross section. I have thought of a few ways to do this. I believe the easiest would be to count the number of people in each cross section for each age.

```
mydata <- dplyr::mutate(group_by(mydata, age, year), nage=n())
```

Then I find the minimum count for each age group across years.

```
mydata <- dplyr::mutate(group_by(mydata, age), minN=min(nage))
```

Now the last part is the part I don't know how to do. I would now like to select the first 1:N observations within each group. The obvious way to do this would be to create an index variable within each group. Then subset the data.frame to only those observations which are less than that index value that counts from 1 to N.

```
mydata <- dplyr::mutate(group_by(mydata, age, year), index=index())
subset(mydata, index <= minN)
```

Of course this is the problem. The function `index` does not exist. I have written out this entire explanation so that either someone can provide the function I am looking for or someone can suggest an alternative method to accomplish this same objective, or both. Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old solution:

```
mydata %>% group_by(age, year) %>%  
    mutate(nage=n()) %>% 
    group_by(age) %>% 
    filter(row_number()%in%1:min(nage))
```

Final solution:

```
mydata %>% 
   group_by(age, year) %>% 
   mutate(nage=n()) %>% 
   group_by(age) %>% 
   mutate(minN = min(nage)) %>% 
   group_by(age, year) %>% 
   slice(seq_len(minN[1L]))
```

Comment: Don't think it works since the filter is grabbing observations indiscriminately from across years. I modified your first submission to make this work. `mydata %>% 
  group_by(age, year) %>% 
  mutate(nage=n()) %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  mutate(minN = min(nage)) %>%
  group_by(age, year) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(minN[1L]))`